# Xamarin AnimationEnd event triggering only once

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-animation

So i have this few lines of code where i try to make an animation loop. Unfortunately it only triggers once not every time the event stops. Can you please help me?

```
ImageView imgView1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.falling_stars1);
ImageView imgView2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.falling_stars2);

Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator animator1 = Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imgView1, "y", -700, 100);
Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator animator2 = Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imgView2, "y", 100, 900);

animator1.SetDuration(2000);
animator2.SetDuration(2000);
animator1.Start();
animator2.Start();

animator1.AnimationEnd += delegate
{
    animator1.Start();
};

animator2.AnimationEnd += delegate
{
    animator2.Start();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RepeatMode: Defines the animation behavior when it reaches the end and the repeat count is greater than 0 or infinite.`

```
Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator animator1 = Android.Animation.ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(imgView1, "y", -700, 100);
animator1.SetDuration(2000);
animator1.RepeatCount = ValueAnimator.Infinite;
animator1.RepeatMode = ValueAnimatorRepeatMode.Restart;
```

Comment: Add a description of the changes you're proposing here.

Comment: Can i edit the animation so it ends and stars abruptly? If is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean to end and start abruptly? Do you want it to stop mid-action?

Comment: I mean the animation slows down at the end a little. I want it to have a constant speed on the entire duration. I want to do a falling stars backscreen with 2 images following eachother but the speed is not constant.